# How do I connect to a folder on a Remote Computer? (in R)

Tags: windows, remote-access, r, remote-connection

I have some .csv files in a folder on a remote computer, and I would like to connect to that folder and load the files into R.

I have the name of the computer, the userid and password. Is there a command that will let me connect to that folder?

Comment: Not only should you detail your operating systems for your remote computer and your working computer, you should probably ask this on a "basic computing questions" web site.

Comment: Both the local computer and the remote computer use the windows operating system.

Comment: This doesn't look like a data science question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like Samba or FTP. Samba shares are pretty easy if you are on local network on both Windows and Linux. If it is not on local network, you should use something like SFTP, but you may need to enable port forwarding in the router of the remote computer. You can use FileZilla as server.